# Importing external dependencies in Typescript

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, dependencies, export

I am a newbie in typescript/node. I have a typescript file "order.ts" from which I would like to import an external config dependency from "config.ts"

My config file code is as below

```
let config = {
    mongoAddress: "mongodb://localhost:27017/dts",
    dataDirectory: "../../data/"
};

module.exports = config;
```

I am importing the config file in the order file as below

```
import { config  } from "../../config";
```

However I am getting the TS compiler throwing error "... file not a module". Any clues how I should I be importing my external dependency in typescript

[image]

Comment: try this---
 export const config = {
    mongoAddress: "mongodb://localhost:27017/dts",
    dataDirectory: "../../data/"
};

Comment: That worked :) ... Thanks Ajay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 ways you can do import and export.

1) default export

```
// config.ts
export const config = {
    mongoAddress: "mongodb://localhost:27017/dts",
    dataDirectory: "../../data/"
};
export default config;

// your other file

import configs from './config';
```

Note: Here you can give any name for the imported module;

2) normal export with exact declaration name while importing.

```
// config.ts
export const config = {
    mongoAddress: "mongodb://localhost:27017/dts",
    dataDirectory: "../../data/"
};

// your other file
import { config  } from './config';
```

Note: Here you have to give the exact name of the module that you exported.

Best practices to follow while exporting configs.

create a static class with static variables in the code. Which likely means that these configs are fixed stuffs.

Answer (score 2):

The main part here is you want to **export your object** instance. You're on the right track with that, but there may be an easier way for you.

In this case something like wrapping it in a class and exporting that:

```
export class Config {
    mongoAddress = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/dts';
    dataDirectory = '../../data/';
}
```

Notice the `export` before class. The same can be applied to interfaces, enums etc. By exporting it this way you can then import it and initialise it:

```
import { Config } from '../config';

var c = new Config();
console.log(c.mongoAddress);
```

This will not make it a variable, like in your original example, but you'll simply wrap it in a class. This is also why you have to initialise it first using `new Config()`.

Now, I'm assuming you want these properties simply to be accessed globally. And perhaps even static/readonly, so you don't have to initialise the class each time. Making use of the static typing of TypeScript, the sample would in this case be better refactored to something like this:

```
export class Config {
    public static readonly mongoAddress: string = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/dts';
    public static readonly dataDirectory: string = '../../data/';
}
```

With this, calling it is even less obtrusive - and very type safe:

```
console.log(Config.mongoAddress);
console.log(Config.dataDirectory);
```

Now exporting this way is just one of the options. It actually depends entirely on the [library structure you're using](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/library-structures.html) throughout your application (or from third partie libraries, for that matter). It's a bit of dry reading, but I recommend you have a look at the different structures to get acquainted with terms like UMD and modules and how they relate to an import.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

`module.exports` is the node syntax for exporting modules. Typescript has a keyword names `export` so you can just use this:

```
export const config = {
    mongoAddress: "mongodb://localhost:27017/dts",
    dataDirectory: "../../data/"
};
```